# Problem with owned types mapping in EF Core 3.0

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0

I've migrated from EF Core Preview5 to Preview7 and now I have same internal complex properties mapping through select.

For example:

```
public class Car
{
    public Volume Volume { get; set; }
    public string OtherProperty { get; set; }
}

[Owned]
public class Volume
{
    public float Height { get; set; }
    public float Width { get; set; }
    public float Length { get; set;}
}
```

Earlier, the code `modelBuilder.Entity<Car>().OwnsOne(e => e.Volume)` worked properly, but now it needs to use `WithOwner` but I can't understand (see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes)
I can't use code like this: `modelBuilder.Entity<Car>().OwnsOne(e => e.Volume).WithOwner("Car")` or `modelBuilder.Entity<Car>().OwnsOne(e => e.Volume).WithOwner(f => f.Car)`.
Does anyone have the same problem?

Thanks.

Update.

I've checked OrderStoreDbContextModelSnapshot.cs. I've posted here other example fully congruent with the upper example.

```
modelBuilder.Entity("DatabaseServiceNew.Database.Order_information.OrderProfile", b =>
            {
                b.HasOne("DatabaseService.Database.Order_information.Order", "Order")
                    .WithOne("OrderProfile")
                    .HasForeignKey("DatabaseServiceNew.Database.Order_information.OrderProfile", "OrderId")
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                    .IsRequired();

                b.OwnsOne("FoundationClasses.Technical_Classes.Volume", "Volume", b1 =>
                    {
                        b1.Property<Guid>("OrderProfileId");

                        b1.Property<float>("Cum");

                        b1.Property<float>("Height");

                        b1.Property<float>("Length");

                        b1.Property<float>("Width");

                        b1.HasKey("OrderProfileId");

                        b1.ToTable("OrderProfiles");

                        b1.WithOwner()
                            .HasForeignKey("OrderProfileId");
                    });

                b.OwnsOne("WebFoundationClassesCore.Data_classes.GeoPoint", "EndPoint", b1 =>
                    {
                        b1.Property<Guid>("OrderProfileId");

                        b1.Property<string>("Address");

                        b1.Property<double>("Latitude");

                        b1.Property<double>("Longitude");

                        b1.HasKey("OrderProfileId");

                        b1.ToTable("OrderProfiles");

                        b1.WithOwner()
                            .HasForeignKey("OrderProfileId");
                    });

                b.OwnsOne("WebFoundationClassesCore.Data_classes.GeoPoint", "StartPoint", b1 =>
                    {
                        b1.Property<Guid>("OrderProfileId");

                        b1.Property<string>("Address");

                        b1.Property<double>("Latitude");

                        b1.Property<double>("Longitude");

                        b1.HasKey("OrderProfileId");

                        b1.ToTable("OrderProfiles");

                        b1.WithOwner()
                            .HasForeignKey("OrderProfileId");
                    });
            });
```

where

```
[Owned, ComplexType]
public class Volume
{
    public float Height { get; set; }
    public float Width { get; set; }
    public float Length { get; set;}
}


[Owned, ComplexType]
public class GeoPoint 
{
    public GeoPoint() 
    {
    }
    public GeoPoint(double latitude, double longitude, string address) 
    {
        this.Address = address;
        this.Latitude = latitude;
        this.Longitude = longitude;
    }

    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set;}
}
```

So, as we can see, ContextSnapshot maps data correctly (ComplexType attribute do nothing in real in this case, experimentally).

`OrderStoreDbContext` has `public DbSet<OrderProfile> OrderProfiles { get; set; }` property.

But linq request `var orderProfiles = await orderDbContext.OrderProfiles.ToListAsync();` maps just simple types (which are exist in the OrderProfiles table, but not complex.
`var orderProfiles = await orderDbContext.OrderProfiles.Include(p => p.Volume).ToListAsync();` code also has no effect - I get `orderProfiles.Volume` and `orderProfiles.StartPoint` and `orderProfiles.EndPoint` values as `null`.

But, in the Preview5 this code works fine. Has microsoft developers broken complex type mapping in EF Core 3.0 Preview7 or the problem in my curved hands?

Update 2.
Posted an issue on github project repo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`WithOwner` fluent API is still undocumented (normal for preview software), but it follows the relationship API (`HasOne` / `HasMany` / `WithOne`, `WithMany`) pattern for navigation property - if you have navigation property, pass either lambda expression or the name of the property (string)). If you don't have navigation property, don't pass anything.

You can see that for one of the `WithOwner` overloads using Go To Definition Command is VS:

```
//
// Summary:
//     Configures the relationship to the owner.
//     Note that calling this method with no parameters will explicitly configure this
//     side of the relationship to use no navigation property, even if such a property
//     exists on the entity type. If the navigation property is to be used, then it
//     must be specified.
//
// Parameters:
//   ownerReference:
//     The name of the reference navigation property pointing to the owner. If null
//     or not specified, there is no navigation property pointing to the owner.
//
// Returns:
//     An object that can be used to configure the relationship.
public virtual OwnershipBuilder<TEntity, TDependentEntity> WithOwner([CanBeNullAttribute] string ownerReference = null);
```

Same is shown by VS Intellisense.

So in your case, just use `WithOwner()`, e.g.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Car>().OwnsOne(e => e.Volume).WithOwner()
    . /* configuration goes here */
```

Comment: Ivan, thank you! I've wided description of my question - the problem is deeper than I've thought before.

Comment: I've tried to add your code modelBuilder.Entity<Car>().OwnsOne(e => e.Volume).WithOwner() with and without ContextSnapshot code (commented it) - no effect, still not mapped complex types...

Comment: The new problem is not related to mapping - they are mapped correctly, saved correctly, but not loaded (just checked that). The last of course is a bug. This is normal (or expected) for preview software, you can't expect it to work properly. If that was the original question, I wouldn't even looking at or posting an answer. Please revert the question update, it really has to be a new question (or no question - see the comment about preview software),

Comment: Yes, Ivan, I'll close this question - You've given full and exact answer. Now I want to past it in the community for bug fixing (in Preview5 it worked fine).